# Controller Action not firing after disabling Submit button in jquery in file upload

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, jquery

I have Upload button after filepload control but after disbaling button my actionmethod in controller is not been called.Please find below code:
In JQUERY:

```
  $(document).ready(function () {
            $("input[type=submit]").removeAttr("disabled");
            $("#btnUpload").click(function () {

               $('#progressbardiv').show();
               $("input[type=submit]").attr("disabled", "disabled");

            });
        });
```

In Action in controller:

```
/// <summary>
        /// Action on Upload button click
        /// </summary>
        /// <returns>ActionResult</returns>
        [AcceptVerbs(HttpVerbs.Post)]
        public ActionResult Upload(HttpPostedFileBase fileUpload)
        {     
}
```

Comment: Probably you need to re-atach the click/submit event?

Answer (score 0):

`disabled` elements **don't fire events**. You'll have to re-enable it in order for it to fire the submit.

Comment: Hi...But In my another scenario where i dont have fileupload ...same code is working